# Select query that will look at digits to left and right of dash and perform a select top based on both values

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Here is an example of what the values of the column in my table will look like 
18-0267, 19-0001, 19-0002, 19-SHOP

So what I need to do is first split the digits to the left of the '-' and see if those digits are in fact from the current year such as 19 = 2019 or 18 = 2018.

After this I need to get the characters to the right of the '-' and check if they are in fact '%[0,9]%' and if they are I would like to select the Top 1 Order by DESC, but that top value has to take into effect the current year to the left side digits.

I thought that I had it from the query below, but that was until I realized I was not checking the digits to the left of the '-' to make sure the top value is from the current year

So from the numbers in the example above I would like to return the 19-0002 value but really I just want to return 0002 and right now the query is returning the value of 18-0267 and I am getting the 0267.

Any help is appreciated thank you

```
SELECT TOP 1
  RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) AS 'Name'
FROM Job
WHERE RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Comment: Please include some sample data and your expected/desired results preferably formatted as text.

Comment: So 'Name' is the column name and some values of column name would be '18-0267', '19-0001', '19-0002', '19-SHOP' So there is the possibility of having characters that are not digits to the right of the '-', but what I want to do is get the highest value for the current year so in the example '19-0002' is the highest value for 2019, and I want to disregard the '18-0267' because that is a 2018 column value and not in the current year. I also want to disregard the '19-SHOP' because I only want to take into effect the highest numeric value

Comment: Down votes are anonymous--it wasn't me. A downvote indicates that someone thought your question was unclear. I edited your sql because it was all on one line and hard to read. Capitalization of SQL keywords is standard. If you don't like the edit you can always re-edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what `name` refers to.  Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) AS New_Name
FROM Job j
WHERE RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
ORDER BY j.Name DESC;
```

Your alias called `Name` was being confused with the column called `Name`.

If you want to ensure that the right two columns are for the current year, then you need to include that in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) AS New_Name
FROM Job j
WHERE RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)) - 1) LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND
      DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) LIKE '__' + LEFT(NAME, 2) 
ORDER BY j.Name DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't think of that at all! I tried to upvote your answer, but I am sadly to inexperienced for it to show haha!

Comment: This won't work if you have future values like `20-0001` when the current year is 2019

Comment: @Sentinel . . . I thought about that and it didn't seem relevant to the problem in the OP's question.  That said, because you brought up the point, I added filtering logic in.

Comment: I have it built into code that they cannot enter left digits for a future year, but that is a good catch thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that limits based on the leading two characters being the current two digit year:

```
select TOP 1 RIGHT(job.Name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(job.Name)) - 1) name
  from job
 where job.name like left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 12),2) + '-[0-9]%'
 order by 1 desc;
```

Relying on sorting by job.name in descending order will not work if you have future years in the job table.